# Labels positions

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, silverlight, scichart

I have scichart graph. The Scichart label is hidden because of too much digits.
how to make it visible?
Maybe margin it some pixels left?
How to control the margin of label through xaml or code behind?

the xaml i wrote for the graph :

```
<UserControl x:Class="EZTrader.Graph.GraphView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:EZTrader.Converters"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:graph="clr-namespace:EZTrader.Graph"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:s="http://schemas.abtsoftware.co.uk/scichart"
         xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
         x:Name="GraphControlEx"
         d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance graph:GraphViewModel}"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="400"
         mc:Ignorable="d">
<UserControl.Resources>
    <converters:NullToVisibilityConverter x:Key="NullToVisibilityConverter" />
    <Style x:Key="GridLineStyle"
           TargetType="Line">
        <Setter Property="Stroke"
                Value="{StaticResource ChartGridLineBrush}" />
    </Style>
    <Style x:Key="AxisLabelStyle"
           TargetType="s:DefaultTickLabel">
        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                Value="Pink" />
    </Style>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="LastTickTemplate"
                     TargetType="Control">
        <Border Name="PART_BoxAnnotationRoot"
                Width="10"
                Height="10"
                Margin="-5,-5,0,0">
            <Ellipse Fill="{StaticResource CurrentValueBrush}" />
        </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>

</UserControl.Resources>

<t:BusyIndicator IsBusy="{Binding IsLoadingGraph}">
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <graph:GraphHeaderView Grid.Row="0"
                               DataContext="{Binding HeaderViewModel}"
                               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot,
                                                    Path=DataContext.HeaderViewModel,
                                                    Converter={StaticResource NullToVisibilityConverter}}" />

        <s:SciStockChart x:Name="Chart"
                         Grid.Row="1"
                         IsPanEnabled="True"
                         IsRubberBandZoomEnabled="False"
                         SeriesSource="{Binding SeriesViewModels}"
                         s:ThemeManager.Theme="EZ">
            <s:SciStockChart.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="../Resources/Images/ChartBackground.jpg" />
            </s:SciStockChart.Background>
            <s:SciChartSurface.RenderSurface >
                <s:HighQualityRenderSurface Rendered="Rendered_Event" />
            </s:SciChartSurface.RenderSurface>
            <s:SciStockChart.GridLinesPanelStyle>
                <Style TargetType="Control">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                            Value="{StaticResource ChartGridLineBrush}" />
                </Style>
            </s:SciStockChart.GridLinesPanelStyle>
            <s:SciStockChart.XAxisStyle>
                <Style TargetType="s:CategoryDateTimeAxis">
                    <Setter Property="BarTimeFrame" Value="{Binding BarTimeFrame, Mode=OneWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="VisibleRange" Value="{Binding XVisibleRange, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMinorGridLines" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="DrawMajorTicks" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMajorBands" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMajorGridLines" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawLabels" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMinorTicks" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="GrowBy" Value="0, 0.1"/>
                </Style>
            </s:SciStockChart.XAxisStyle>

            <s:SciStockChart.YAxisStyle>

                <Style TargetType="s:NumericAxis">

                    <Setter Property="CursorTextFormatting" Value="0.000###"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="AutoRange" Value="Always"/>
                    <Setter Property="TickTextBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMinorGridLines" Value="False" />
                    <Setter Property="DrawMajorTicks" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMajorBands" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMajorGridLines" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawLabels" Value="True"/>
                    <Setter Property="DrawMinorTicks" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextFormatting" Value="0.#######" />
                </Style>
            </s:SciStockChart.YAxisStyle>
        </s:SciStockChart>

        <ListBox Grid.Row="1"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top"
                 Margin="20"
                 ItemsSource="{Binding ZoomOptions}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedZoomOption, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name">
            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Setter Property="Width"
                            Value="30" />
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        </ListBox>
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0,30,70,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="200">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <ComboBox Grid.Column="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SeriesStyles}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSeriesStyle,
                                         Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="10,0,0,0" />

        </Grid>

    </Grid>
</t:BusyIndicator>
```

the image:

[image]